# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/

Tags: java, android

EDIT:Ok I have tried the suggestions and changed it to getExternalFilesDir() and am still getting the same error. Skip to the bottom where it says "EDITED CODE" to see what it is now. I also changed it so that the screenshot will save to the pictures directory instead of creating a new directory. (END EDIT)

I have an android app that contains a recyclerview. I have created a button that will export create a PNG of the recyclerview data, save it to the device, and then send it as an attachment to the email application so it can be emailed. I'm getting the exception " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/ExportedFlares/FlareData.png"

Here is the code for the function that saves the bitmap to the device:

```
 private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    if(bitmap!=null){
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                        "/ExportedFlares";
                File dir = new File(file_path, "FlareData");
                if(!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dir); //here is set your file path where you want to save or also here you can set file object directly

                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream); // bitmap is your Bitmap instance, if you want to compress it you can compress reduce percentage
                // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the onClick code for when the button is tapped:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            saveBitmap(getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(recyclerView));

            String filename = "FlareData.png";
            File fileLocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                    "/ExportedFlares", filename);
            Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(FlareActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",fileLocation);

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
            String to[] = {"email@gmail.com"};
            emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

            emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);

            emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
```

The final line of the following code is what is throwing the exception:

```
File fileLocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                    "/ExportedFlares", filename);
            Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(FlareActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",fileLocation);
```

Here is the XML data, I have provider_paths.xml here:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="FlareData.png" path="ExportedFlares/"/>
</paths>
```

And this is from the manifest:

```
enter code here
        <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

EDITED CODE:

```
emailFlaresButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            saveBitmap(context, getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(recyclerView));


                String filename = "FlareData.png";
                File fileLocation = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()
, filename);
                Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(FlareActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",fileLocation);

                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
                String to[] = {"asd@gmail.com"};
                emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

                emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);

                emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send 
                email..."));
                // Intent intent = new Intent(FlareActivity.this, 
                AddFlareActivity.class);
                //startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_FLARE_RESULT_CODE);
            }
        });
```

And here is the piece of code that the error is pointing to (the last line) :

```
                Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(FlareActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",fileLocation);
```

I have tried it with the provider path being set to both external-files-path and external-path and it doesn't affect the issue

EDIT3: Full stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.fibrnah, PID: 22052
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.fibrnah/files/Pictures/FlareData.png
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
    at com.android.fibrnah.FlareActivity$2.onClick(FlareActivity.java:84)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6274)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24859)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your XML metadata resource that you set up for `FileProvider`? Something in there does not match your Java.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated it with the XML data

Answer (score 0):

Change `external-files-path` to `external-path`.

Or, put your files in `getExternalFilesDir()` (called on a `Context`). This is the better solution, as your current code will not work on Android Q (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps).

Comment: I appreciate the info! I have updated the post above with what I have implemented per your suggestions but it is still giving the same error

Comment: @Jarf: Replace `new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath(), filename)` with `new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES), filename)`. If you still are running into problems, edit your question and provide the full stack trace associated with your current code.

Comment: still getting the same error. I edited it with the stacktrace

Comment: @Jarf: Remove `path="ExportedFlares/"` from your metadata. That says "look in the root for a directory named `ExportedFlares/` and serve files from there", but you do not have that directory.